# problem with line-break after paragraph-level sectioning header in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking

[image]

how to solve the problem with paragraph's page number showing up on the line below the associated sectioning header?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.} 
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Le néphron}
\paragraph{Le corpuscule rénal \\}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post more than just a screenshot of the problem. To fix the typographic problem, we need to know what gives rise to the problem. Please also tell us which document class you use and if you use any packages (such as `tocloft`) that modify the appearance of the table of contents.

Comment: `\paragraph{Le corpuscule rénal \\}` is causing the problem. Remove the linebreak directive and the problem in the table of contents goes away.

Comment: it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Did you rerun LaTeX twice after removing the linebreak directive?

Comment: it works ! but how can i make a line break now ?

Comment: See the answer I just posted.

Comment: `\paragraph` is defined as an in-line heading, you can change that by changing its declaration, either directly or using a package, you should never need to end the heading text with `\\ ` just define `\paragraph` to be a display heading like `\subsection` so the line break is automatic.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by the line-break directive (`\\`) in

```
\paragraph{Le corpuscule rénal \\}
```

Consider removing it. If you absolutely must have a line-break after the paragraph-level sectioning header, I suggest you write

```
\paragraph[Le corpuscule rénal]{Le corpuscule rénal\\}
```

That way, the line-break won't show up in the table of contents.

---

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{14} % just for this example

\section{\dots}
\setcounter{subsection}{2}
\subsection{Structure du parenchyme rénal}
\subsubsection{Le néphron}
\paragraph[Le corpuscule rénal]{Le corpuscule rénal\\}
bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @cfr and @DavidCarlisle have pointed out in comments, another way to solve the OP's issue would be to modify the `\paragraph` macro, so that a line break gets inserted automatically at the end of all `paragraph`-level sectioning headers. This solution would certainly seem preferable if the document features more than just a couple of `\paragraph` instructions.

To pursue this solution, simply insert the following code in the preamble -- and remove the `\\` directives at the end of the arguments of the `\paragraph` directives:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\paragraph{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}{-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{}{}
\makeatother
\patchcmd\paragraph{-1em}{1em}{}{}
```

Comment: @Jdoe If the answer solved the problem, you should accept it by clicking the greyed-out checkmark at the top left of the answer.

Comment: @cfr - Thanks. I've posted an addendum to show how to redefine the format of the `\paragraph` instruction.